# react native prompt user to download app from App Store

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I need to have the react native application prompt me to download the linkedIn app when the app is note installed and the url is opened in the browser

what I want to do is once its open it browser to prompt the user to download from App Store in both iOS and android. Please advise if you can thanks!

```
       Linking.canOpenURL('https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates').then(supported => {
            if (supported) {
              Linking.openURL('https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates');
            } else {
              console.log("Don't know how to open URI: " + 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates');
            }
          });
```

Comment: solution was natural behavior was to direct to browswer where a smart banner is displayed to route to app store. so this very code was correct.